# Rearrange $ax + by + cz = d$ into a linear combination form

Tags: linear-algebra

Linear combinations of two linearly independent $3$-component vectors fill up a plane in $3D$ space. The equation $ax + by + cz = d$ does the same. How can we rewrite this equation into a linear combination of two linearly independent $3$-component vectors? I am trying to do  this since this is the best way for me to visualize an equation. Best I can do so far is $\begin{bmatrix} a \\ b \\ c \\ \end{bmatrix} \cdot \begin{bmatrix} x \\ y \\ z \\ \end{bmatrix} = d$, but that doesn't look like a linear combination.

Answer (score 0):

It looks as though you're trying to characterize the space of vectors $(x,y,z)$ satisfying
$$
ax + by + cz = d
$$
as the linear combinations of two vectors, i.e. 
$$
(x,y,z) = s(x_1,y_1,z_1) + t(x_2,y_2,z_2) \text{ for } s,t \in \Bbb R
$$
In general, this is only possible when $d = 0$.  Otherwise, we will necessarily have a plane that doesn't pass through the origin, i.e.
$$
(x,y,z) = (x_0,y_0,z_0)+ s(x_1,y_1,z_1) + t(x_2,y_2,z_2) \text{ for } s,t \in \Bbb R
$$
where $(x_0,y_0,z_0)$ is any solution to the equation and the other two are solutions to the problem with $d = 0$.

Assuming all values $a,b,c,d$ are non-zero, we could always write the solution as follows:
$$
(x,y,z) = (d/a,0,0) + s(b,-a,0) + t(0,c,-b) \text{ for } s,t \in \Bbb R
$$
when some values are zero, we have to change this around to make sure that we don't divide by zero and that all vectors in the expression are non-zero.